# How to detect color of the center of camera streaming in android without OpenCV

Tags: android, android-camera, pixel, color-picker

Any approach to detect color of the center of image after starting camera preview ?

```
(My problem is solved thanks for help)
```

I've just developed a solution to detect average color of a stream of data of image taken with android camera.

Here is my code, I trying to take image each 500 ms and crop the center (square of 60*60) then get average of color.

```
public class TakePicture extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
// a variable to store a reference to the Image View at the main.xml file
private ImageView iv_image;
// a variable to store a reference to the Surface View at the main.xml file
private SurfaceView sv;

// a bitmap to display the captured image
private Bitmap bmp;

// Camera variables
// a surface holder
private SurfaceHolder sHolder;
// a variable to control the camera
Camera mCamera;
// the camera parameters
private Parameters parameters;
Camera.PictureCallback mCall;
Button takePicture;
Handler handler;
TextView colorName, Hex;
SharedPreferences pref;
Editor editor;
int width = 0, height = 0;
private Camera.Size pictureSize;

boolean mStopHandler = false;
private static final HashMap<String, String> sColorNameMap;

static {
    sColorNameMap = new HashMap();
    sColorNameMap.put("#000000", "black");
    sColorNameMap.put("#A9A9A9", "darkgray");
    sColorNameMap.put("#808080", "gray");
    sColorNameMap.put("#D3D3D3", "lightgray");
    sColorNameMap.put("#FFFFFF", "white");
    // .....

}

Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (mCamera != null) {
            // do your stuff - don't create a new runnable here!
            mCamera.takePicture(null, null, mCall);

            if (!mStopHandler) {
                handler.postDelayed(this, 500);
            }
        }
    }
};

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    handler = new Handler();
    pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0);
    editor = pref.edit();
    colorName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.colorName);
    Hex = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.colorHex);
    // get the Image View at the main.xml file
    iv_image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    takePicture = (Button) findViewById(R.id.takePicture);

    // get the Surface View at the main.xml file
    sv = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surfaceView);

    // Get a surface
    sHolder = sv.getHolder();

    // add the callback interface methods defined below as the Surface View
    // callbacks
    sHolder.addCallback(this);

    // tells Android that this surface will have its data constantly
    // replaced
    sHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    takePicture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mCamera.takePicture(null, null, mCall);

        }
    });
}

@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder sv, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
    // get camera parameters
    parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
    // parameters.setPreviewFormat(ImageFormat.NV21);
    mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
    setBesttPictureResolution();

    mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
    try {
        mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(sv);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
    // set camera parameters
    mCamera.startPreview();

    // sets what code should be executed after the picture is taken
    mCall = new Camera.PictureCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
            // decode the data obtained by the camera into a Bitmap
            if (data != null) {
                bmp = decodeBitmap(data);
            }
            // set the iv_image
            if (bmp != null) {
                ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                // bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 70, bytes);
                Bitmap resizebitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp,
                        bmp.getWidth() / 2, bmp.getHeight() / 2, 60, 60);
                iv_image.setImageBitmap(rotateImage(resizebitmap, 90));

                int color = getAverageColor(resizebitmap);
                Log.i("Color Int", color + "");
                // int color =
                // resizebitmap.getPixel(resizebitmap.getWidth()/2,resizebitmap.getHeight()/2);

                String strColor = String.format("#%06X", 0xFFFFFF & color);
                Hex.setText(strColor);
                String colorname = sColorNameMap.get(strColor);
                if (colorName != null) {
                    colorName.setText(colorname);
                }

                Log.i("Pixel Value",
                        "Top Left pixel: " + Integer.toHexString(color));
            }

        }
    };
}

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    // The Surface has been created, acquire the camera and tell it where
    // to draw the preview.
    // mCamera = Camera.open();
    mCamera = getCameraInstance();
    if (mCamera != null) {
        try {
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
            handler.post(runnable);

        } catch (IOException exception) {
            mCamera.release();
            mCamera = null;
        }
    } else
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Camera is not available",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {

    if (mCamera != null) {
        // stop the preview
        mCamera.stopPreview();
        // release the camera
        mCamera.release();
    }
    // unbind the camera from this object
    if (handler != null)
        handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
}

public static Bitmap decodeBitmap(byte[] data) {

    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    BitmapFactory.Options bfOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    bfOptions.inDither = false; // Disable Dithering mode
    bfOptions.inPurgeable = true; // Tell to gc that whether it needs free
                                    // memory, the Bitmap can be cleared
    bfOptions.inInputShareable = true; // Which kind of reference will be
                                        // used to recover the Bitmap data
                                        // after being clear, when it will
                                        // be used in the future
    bfOptions.inTempStorage = new byte[32 * 1024];

    if (data != null)
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length,
                bfOptions);

    return bitmap;
}

public Bitmap rotateImage(Bitmap src, float degree) {
    // create new matrix object
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    // setup rotation degree
    matrix.postRotate(degree);
    // return new bitmap rotated using matrix
    return Bitmap.createBitmap(src, 0, 0, src.getWidth(), src.getHeight(),
            matrix, true);
}

public int getAverageColor(Bitmap bitmap) {
    int redBucket = 0;
    int greenBucket = 0;
    int blueBucket = 0;
    int pixelCount = 0;

    for (int y = 0; y < bitmap.getHeight(); y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < bitmap.getWidth(); x++) {
            int c = bitmap.getPixel(x, y);

            pixelCount++;
            redBucket += Color.red(c);
            greenBucket += Color.green(c);
            blueBucket += Color.blue(c);
            // does alpha matter?
        }
    }

    int averageColor = Color.rgb(redBucket / pixelCount, greenBucket
            / pixelCount, blueBucket / pixelCount);
    return averageColor;
}

int[] averageARGB(Bitmap pic) {
    int A, R, G, B;
    A = R = G = B = 0;
    int pixelColor;
    int width = pic.getWidth();
    int height = pic.getHeight();
    int size = width * height;

    for (int x = 0; x < width; ++x) {
        for (int y = 0; y < height; ++y) {
            pixelColor = pic.getPixel(x, y);
            A += Color.alpha(pixelColor);
            R += Color.red(pixelColor);
            G += Color.green(pixelColor);
            B += Color.blue(pixelColor);
        }
    }

    A /= size;
    R /= size;
    G /= size;
    B /= size;

    int[] average = { A, R, G, B };
    return average;

}

private void setBesttPictureResolution() {
    // get biggest picture size
    width = pref.getInt("Picture_Width", 0);
    height = pref.getInt("Picture_height", 0);

    if (width == 0 | height == 0) {
        pictureSize = getBiggesttPictureSize(parameters);
        if (pictureSize != null)
            parameters
                    .setPictureSize(pictureSize.width, pictureSize.height);
        // save width and height in sharedprefrences
        width = pictureSize.width;
        height = pictureSize.height;
        editor.putInt("Picture_Width", width);
        editor.putInt("Picture_height", height);
        editor.commit();

    } else {
        // if (pictureSize != null)
        parameters.setPictureSize(width, height);
    }
}

private Camera.Size getBiggesttPictureSize(Camera.Parameters parameters) {
    Camera.Size result = null;

    for (Camera.Size size : parameters.getSupportedPictureSizes()) {
        if (result == null) {
            result = size;
        } else {
            int resultArea = result.width * result.height;
            int newArea = size.width * size.height;

            if (newArea > resultArea) {
                result = size;
            }
        }
    }

    return (result);
}

/** A safe way to get an instance of the Camera object. */
public Camera getCameraInstance() {
    Camera c = null;
    try {
        c = Camera.open(); // attempt to get a Camera instance
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Camera is not available (in use or does not exist)
    }
    return c; // returns null if camera is unavailable
}
```

}

Comment: it starts with "i want" - and then only hot air.

Comment: what the wrong ? I spend one day in searching for any solution but I failed so I posted my problem here for any help no for negative reputation. @berak

Comment: your 'research' consisted of looking at another app ?

Comment: no it's not related to looking at another app,I've just mention it here to help the others to understand my problem.

Comment: @Heema are you able to detect color successfully during live Camera Preview as well?

Comment: @sam_k Yes, and it's working with me perfectly!

Comment: @Heema Can you please same the code with full demo application, as I also wanted to try same one in my academic project.

Comment: @Heema Can you please share your demo application code. I am looking for the same one which you have implemented.